# How to fix unresolved external symbol due to MySql Connector C++?

Tags: c++, mysql

I followed this tutorial http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/?p=215#hello. I tried both on Visual C++ 2008 and Visual C++ 2010. Either static or dynamic, the compiler gave me the same exact error messages:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _get_driver_instance
```

Has anyone experience this issue before?

Update:
+ Additional Dependencies: mysqlcppconn.lib
+ Additional Include Directories: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.0.5\include
+ Additional Libraries Directories: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.0.5\lib\opt

Another Update:
Click F12 on get_driver_instance() linked to:

```
class CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC Driver
{
protected:
    virtual ~Driver() {}
public:
    // Attempts to make a database connection to the given URL.

    virtual Connection * connect(const std::string& hostName, const std::string& userName, const std::string& password) = 0;

    virtual Connection * connect(std::map< std::string, ConnectPropertyVal > & options) = 0;

    virtual int getMajorVersion() = 0;

    virtual int getMinorVersion() = 0;

    virtual int getPatchVersion() = 0;

    virtual const std::string & getName() = 0;
};

} /* namespace sql */

extern "C"
{
  CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC sql::Driver *get_driver_instance();
}
```

Apparently, the function existed, but the linker could not find it.

Code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include "mysql_driver.h" 

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

int main() {

    try {
        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *conn;
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        conn = driver->connect( "http://localhost/chandb", "root", "chan" );


        stmt = conn->createStatement();
        res = stmt->executeQuery( "select * from another" );
        while( res->next() ) {
            cout << "id = " << res->getInt( "Id" );
            cout << "id = " << res->getInt( "GoldValue" );
            cout << "id = " << res->getString( "Model" );
        }

        delete conn;
        delete stmt;
        delete res;
        std::cout << "This is it";
    }
    catch( sql::SQLException e ) {
        cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: How are you linking your program?

Comment: Probably you don't add some libs when linking.

Comment: I followed the tutorial above at least 3 times. I checked very carefully in both Debug and Release mode. I really couldn't find where I missed :(

Comment: Are you trying to do both dynamic as well as static linking ? You should be doing only one. The tutorial shows to do both and you probably have done it twice.

Comment: I did once and then create another project for another. Thanks!

Comment: @Chan Are there any updates on this? Did you make any headways with your linking issue or is it still problematic?

Comment: I already gave the connector a last try. I was so disappointed. It was very easy when configuring with Eclipse( Java ), but it was painful with C++. I will find another library for mysql.

Comment: @Chan: I was checking the examples of the library, did you try to call sql::mysql::get_driver_instance(); instead of get_driver_instance(); ?.

Comment: @Luis: Thanks. I tried your solution, and VS said:   1>.\main.cpp(24) : error C2039: 'get_driver_instance' : is not a member of 'sql::mysql'

Comment: @Chan: You are including mysql_driver.h in your code?, check this file and you can see that get_driver_instance() is member of sql::mysql.

Answer (score 5):

According to [MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ccpp-news-1-1-0.html) if you are using the Version 1.1 of the MySQL Connector C++:
"get_driver_instance() is now only available in dynamic library builds - static builds do not 
have this symbol. This was done to accommodate loading the DLL with LoadLibrary or dlopen. If you do not use CMake for building the source code you will need to define mysqlcppconn_EXPORTS if you are loading dynamically and want to use the get_driver_instance() entry point."
If I understand the previous note correctly, you have to use the dynamic build and define `mysqlcppconn_EXPORTS`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by define mysqlcppconn_EXPORTS. So I did: #define mysqlcppconn_EXPORTS and I still have the same errors.

Comment: @Chan: Try this: mysqlcppconn_EXPORTS in Project / Properties / C++ / Preprocessor / Preprocessor Definitions, an rebuild your code.

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick reply. However, I did and it still produce the same exact error :(!

Comment: It doesnt work for me as well. Did you find a solution for it Chan?

Answer (score 4):

If you use static linking, you need to set `CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC=` in `Project / Properties / C++ / Preprocessor / Preprocessor Definitions`

Answer (score 2):

I faced Same Error while using c++/Sql Connector.
and after spending entire day I solved this problem by using 32 bit libmysql.dll , 32 bit libmysqlcppcon.lib and 32 bit libmysqlcppcon.dll ( Dynamic binding is used because driver instance creation is only available in dynamic library of libmysqlcppcon.lib)

I found very good link explaining everything along with the working code. I think it would help others if they stuck at the same issue.

http://r3dux.org/2010/11/how-to-use-mysql-connectorc-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-windows/

Comment: Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Answer (score 1):

> error LNK2001: unresolved external
>   symbol _get_driver_instance

That error message basically means that the linker cannot locate the function get_driver_instance anywhere, eg. it's not in any of the object files from your compilation units, not in a static .lib library or import library. This can also happen if the mangled names in the library doesn't match *exactly* with what the linker expects to find. eg. Library was built with different calling convention etc.

I would suggest that you take a look at the final command line being used from your project and update your post here for both compiling and linking. Second, make sure the mysql library you're linking against has that function. I believe there's a commandline tool in vs for dumping and viewing the contents of a static lib.

If you're linking against a dynamic dll version of mysql, make sure the import library contains the missing referenced symbol. Additionally, you can crack the dll open with a PE viewer and look under it's export tables to verify that that function actually exist and is visible.

**Edit:** According to [this post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?167,244004,244019#msg-244019), the function get_driver_instance should be in  'mysqlcppconn.lib' somewhere. Are you sure that file is being properly linked?

Comment: I had the same issue as described above and got it fixed by including mysqlcppconn in the linked included libraries

Answer (score 1):

I read the article you mentioned.
It has this line for **static** compilation : ***As said, you need to link both "mysqlcppconn-static.lib" and "libmysql.lib".***

Since you don't mention this is you question ,have you tried this ?

Also , on a forum I read this (for eclips) "You must have this in source":

```
#include "mysql_driver.h" 
#include "mysql_connection.h"
using namespace sql::mysql;
```

Anyway ,good luck !

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have your heart set on using *this* MySQL Connector/Driver package but there are many robust database wrappers available for free or nearly free out there if this is causing seemingly unspoken headaches for you.

I actually was thoroughly impressed by QT database objects when I used them previously for a data model project.  [The QT framework](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) is licensed under LGPL and also has a commercial version available and is a very versatile set of cross platform libraries.  The QtSql objects provide a consistent interface to many databases including MySql, SQLServer, Postgres, ODBC, etc with the ability to substitute your own drivers and still use the same interface for everything at a high level in C++

Some other notable options:

[SQLApi++](http://www.sqlapi.com/)

[MySQL++](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/)

Not trying to come on like a salesman or anything and I have no affiliation with any of these but sometimes it never hurts to shop around and find something that works better for your needs.

Comment: Great thanks! The reason that I want to use this connector because the ease and clean API it provides; plus I already used J-Connector, so I tried to find something similar. Although I only learn Java for 4 months, but I really like J-Connector design. In fact, the APIs of Connector C++ are basically the same to J-Connector, but the installation part is a bit different. While using it with Eclipse, I only have to add an external jar, and done!

Comment: This amounts to a link-only answer (as it is only linking to other libraries, everything else is waffle).

Answer (score 0):

I solved using the 32bit version both for mysql server and connector/c++ on 64bit OS.
I think the problem are the boost libraries but im not sure.

Comment: This solved the issue for me as well. Although when you do start using the 32 bit version a whole host of errors will spring up out of no where for which you will have to reference the Boost headers.

Answer (score 0):

I spent several hours trying to solve the problem exactly the same as you. I finally found out the problem myself. I downloaded the 64-bit version of MySQL/SQL Connector and followed a tutorial in MySQL.com in setting up win32 console project its properties and got the error message as mentioned. It was because the tutorial is teaching to build a 32-bit program. After I change to build a release version of X64 code, problem was solved. 
Make sure your library is 32bit or 64bit and then configure your Visual Studio accordingly (in configuration manager).

Comment: This is the correct answer. @Chan would mark it to show at the top. It will save lots of time for who is facing this problem. Thank you @ngamc!

Comment: @RenatoAloi It may be the correct answer for you, but for others it may not.

Answer (score 0):

Hello same problem for me, i have search and found my solution, i give you my paths on my local computer, but you can put all where you want, it's just my personnal notes:

The goal is to **compile mysql cpp connector on your computer**, to have lib which work on your computer when you compile somewhat with.

## DEPENDENCIES:

> 1. clone (recursively with submodules, to have the folder jdbc) the repo on master branch (same than 8.0.27 for me when i write this post) of **mysql cpp connector** source code for windows on github:
>
>    - https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp/tree/master
>    - Or if you haven't git, you can do it manualy by download zip: mysql-connector-c++-8.0.27-src.zip: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/
>
>      - and download manualy jdbc by clicking on jdbc folder on this page: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp/tree/master
>      - and the jdbc download must to be unzip and rename by "jdbc", and put in the mysql cpp connector folder
> 2. download **mysql server** for windows:
>
>    - choice: Windows (x86, 64-bit), ZIP Archive
>    - version: 8.0.27
>    - size: 209.4M
>    - url: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/
>    - filename: mysql-8.0.27-winx64
>
>      and put mysql-8.0.27-winx64 in C:\Users\< USER >\Downloads\mysql-8.0.27-winx64
> 3. download **openssl** (Win64 OpenSSL v1.1.1m):
>
>    - binary installer msi: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
>    - it's not official :/ but that work (and it linked by this site too: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries), and i have failed and give up to build from source code)
>    - Install openssl here: E:\OpenSSL-Win64
>    - unfortunaly the version 3.0.1 doesn't work for build cpp connector (or my bad ?)
> 4. download **boost**: https://www.boost.org/users/download/
>
>    - untarGz and put it here: E:\boost_1_78_0

## CONFIGURATION:

> for the configuration you must have this folder architecture:

```
. Parent Folder (for me it's E:\MySql)
|
|\
| \
|  . _SOURCE (renamed mysql cpp connector repo)
|  |
|  .
|  .
|  .
|  |
|  |\
|  | \
|  |  . jdbc (jdbc submodule)
|  .
|  .
|  .
|
|\
| \
|  . _BUILD
 \
  \
   . _INSTALL
```

> with this folder architecture if you have errors in next commands, your sources will not to be modify, you will have just to remove the containt of _BUILD and _INSTALL folders to relaunch
>
> - open powershell in E:\MySql and launch cmd:
>
> cmake .\_SOURCE\ -B .\_BUILD\ -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=.\_INSTALL -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -D WITH_SSL="E:\OpenSSL-Win64" -D BUILD_STATIC=OFF -D WITH_JDBC=ON -D WITH_MYSQL="C:\Users\< USER >\Downloads\mysql-8.0.27-winx64" -D WITH_BOOST="E:\boost_1_78_0" -D MYSQLCLIENT_STATIC_BINDING=OFF -D MYSQLCLIENT_STATIC_LINKING=OFF -G "Visual Studio 16" -A "x64"
>
> - the last lines of output must to be like:
>
> -- Configuring done
>
> -- Generating done
>
> -- Build files have been written to: Your-Build-Path/_BUILD

## BUILDING:

> launch cmd: cmake --build .\_BUILD\
>
> There are a lot of fatal errors possible:
>
> - mysql not found
> - boost not found
> - openssl not found
> - openssl bad version (need 1.1.1)
> - no compatible options values between options
> - forgoten options, if this is the case, try to add the option with his default value
>
> so check yours paths dependecies if you have errors
>
> There somes not fatal warning:
>
> - the "is_same" test doesn't work
> - file sys/endiand.h not found
> - file sys/byteorder.h not found
>
> when the output say "look log files output.log and errors.log" you have fatal error some where, but may be (MAY BE) don't loss time on the warnings and on the logs files... and look all the lines of the ouput, because for me the fatals errors was not listed in the logs files but in the output (may be not for you, i don't know)

## INSTALLATION:

> cmake --install .\_BUILD\ --config Debug

## END:

> in folder: E:\MYSQL\_INSTALL\lib64
> there are dynamic lib
>
> in folder: E:\MYSQL\_INSTALL\lib64\vs14
> there are static lib
>
> and E:\MYSQL\_INSTALL\lib64\vs14\mysqlcppconn.lib
> will containt "get_driver_instance" functions to use mysql cpp connector etc...
> if you want open mysqlcppconn.lib with 7zip, right click, open archive, open 1.txt and 2.txt, and CTRL+F your functions

## NOTES:

> you can't configurate in Debug (-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release), else the first cmake cmd will create a visual studio project (E:\MYSQL\_BUILD\jdbc\connector-jdbc-deps.vcxproj) with inside a unknow linked library (MYSQLLIB-NOTFOUND-DEBUG), and the cmake build cmd will fail
>
> in my visual studio project, i have link the two static lib, and i have copy past the two dynamic lib next to my exe, that work for me

## VERSION-ARCH:

| software | version | arch |
| --- | --- | --- |
| windows pro | 10 | x64 |
| cmake | 3.22.1 | x64 |
| Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 | 16.11.8 | x64 |
| Microsoft .NET Framework | 4.8.04084 | x64 |
| openssl | v1.1.1m | x64 |
| boost | 1.78.0 | cross-arch ? |
| mysql server | 8.0.27 | x64 |
| mysql cpp connector | 8.0.27 | x64 |

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous comments the issue has to do with trying to find a dynamic configuration vs the static configuration.  It also has to do with the 32-bit vs 64-bit.  I had the same issue, and by reading through all the comments I figured out a solution.

First off, you should be using the latest version, which for me was 8.0.33 32-bit.

**mysql-connector-c++-8.0.33-win32**

In the project properties -> VC++ Directories, you'll need to include the directory of the mysql-connector-c++-8.0.33-win32 includes.

**Include Directories:** <...>;**C:<full path>\mysql-connector-c++-8.0.33-win32\include;**

Now in the settings for the Linker, you'll need to have two changes here.

**Additional Library Directories:** **C:<full path>\mysql-connector-c++-8.0.33-win32\lib\vs14**

Finally, you just have to add the correct .lib file, this being the one that isn't static.

**Additional Dependencies:** <...>;**mysqlcppconn.lib;**

One special note that I found while doing implementation is that I had to work with the device/connection within a .cpp file and I couldn't specify my code in a .h file.  I think it had to do with being in the context of a class, and not statically referenced.

Thus, in my .cpp file, at the top I used

**#include <mysql/jdbc.h>**

And then I had access to everything I needed.  You can test all your code out in the **int main()** and refactor afterwards.