# unresolved external symbol on first project MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2012

Tried everything, Search all the day on google. But I didn't success to fix that problem.
Visual Studio says:

```
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver * __cdecl sql::mysql::get_driver_instance(void)" (?get_driver_instance@mysql@sql@@YAPAVMySQL_Driver@12@XZ)
```

SDK: MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.2

What can I do .. ?

Comment: did you add library to lib directories?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix unresolved external symbol due to MySql Connector C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469899/how-to-fix-unresolved-external-symbol-due-to-mysql-connector-c)

Comment: Well, didn't found answer there ..