# Error Building Program with mysql connector

Tags: c++, mysql

I have the following compile time error I cannot find the reason of:
fatal error: mysql_connection.h: No such file or directory

```
/* Standard C++ includes */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

/*
Include directly the different
headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
(and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
cout << endl;
cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' »AS _message'..." << endl;
try {
sql::Driver *driver;
sql::Connection *con;
sql::Statement *stmt;
sql::ResultSet *res;
/* Create a connection */
driver = get_driver_instance();
con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
/* Connect to the MySQL test database */
con->setSchema("test");
stmt = con->createStatement();
res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
while (res->next()) {
cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
/* Access column data by alias or column name */
cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
/* Access column data by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
}
delete res;
delete stmt;
delete con;
} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " »
<< __LINE__ << endl;
cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}
cout << endl;
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am compliling it in Codeblocks and i have installed mysql connector
I am trying it very first time help please !

Comment: Is `mysql_connection.h` in the same folder as the file you're compiling, or in any of the other locations the compiler looks for included files?

Comment: no such file or directory error                                                                        #include <cppconn/connection.h>

Comment: Try `#include`ing `<cppconn/eonnection.h>` instead of `"mysql_connection.h"`, then, or checking to see if there's actually a file named `mysql_connection.h`?  The problem is that it can't find `mysql_connection.h` in any of the locations it searches for user includes.(generally speaking, the current directory (or relative path from it) first, then the locations it would check for `<>` includes if it can't find a match).

Comment: It worked another error i am getting is Fatal error: boost/shared_ptr.hpp : no such file or directory .... for this same code

Comment: Hmm... strange.  Not really sure how to troubleshoot Boost, unfortunately.  Is the directory containing `boost/shared_ptr.hpp` in your include path?

Comment: It's in the include path still getting this error

Comment: It's not included I included and it worked                                                         but i am getting another error that is                                                   undefined refrence to '_imp__get_driver_instance'                                           in the code                                                                                                   driver=get_driver_instance();                                                                                                                                      I am using all this for first time..... help

Comment: Hmm... maybe take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469899/how-to-fix-unresolved-external-symbol-due-to-mysql-connector-c), see if the answers there can solve the problem?

Comment: no the line    driver = get_driver_instance();                                                          still giving an error undefined reference to '_imp__get_driver_instance'                  ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Not sure what to do, then.  Sorry. :(

Answer (score 5):

You are most likely missing libmysqlcppconn-dev. Once installed, the error should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem as you, but on MAC on QtCreator. All what I received is: `cppconn/connection.h file is not found`.

I am not connected to MySQL Server yet. So I commented all Files, that has something to do with the databank. While building I get:

```
library -lGL not found
```

Because the databank was set up on a linux, I had to change the Libraries. So I downloaded first mysql libraries for MAC:

```
brew install mysql-connector-c++
```

then I added them in .pro:

```
mac: {
   LIBS += -framework OpenGL
   INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/opt/mysql-connector-c++/include/cppconn
}
```

after compiling I got the error:

```
boost/scopped_ptr.hpp file not found
```

Here I need to install boost:

```
brew install boost
```

Then add boost in .pro too:

```
mac: {
   LIBS += -framework OpenGL
   INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/opt/mysql-connector-c++/include/cppconn /usr/local/opt/boost/include
}
```

Now I am getting again an Error:

```
symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
linker command failed with exit code 1
```

**Update:**

So my .pro looks like this at the end:

```
unix:!macx {
     LIBS += -lGL
     LIBS += -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib -lmysqlcppconn
     INCLUDEPATH += -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/cppconn
}

macx: {
    LIBS += -framework OpenGL -L/usr/local/opt/mysql-connector-c++/lib -lmysqlcppconn
    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/opt/mysql-connector-c++/lib
    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/opt/mysql-connector-c++/include/cppconn /usr/local/opt/boost/include /usr/local/opt/mysql-connector-c++/include
}
```

it seemed in the `INCLUDEPATH` for macx I needed to mention the missing library which is `mysqlcppconn`. The `-l` helps to figure out that this is the name of the library.

and it actually do work. Now all what needed is a connection to the server.