# Connect C++ program to extract table from MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql

I am currently having internship and my job required me to use C++ to code a program. What I have learned in my college is totally basic.
So basically I need to code a program to calculate user's activeness from a MySQL due to the database have 500k+ users and 13million+ rows.
What I'm trying to do is to code a program to list down user by ID with loop and cout the month they're active during 2019-2020. I have done this part.
Now I can't connect to MySQL which is in the server, I wanna connect it via IP and port. I've tried to find solutions for these errors for 2 days but I can't find a solution so I came here to ask.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
  Include directly the different
  headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
  (and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/
#include <mysql_connection.h>
//#include <mysql_driver.h>

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try {
        sql::Driver* driver;
        sql::Connection* con;
        sql::Statement* stmt;
        sql::ResultSet* res;

        /* Create a connection */
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("tcp://123.123.12.3:3306", "id", "pass"); 
        /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
        con->setSchema("db");

        /*
        int user_id = 1;
        int activity = 0;
        int timestamp;


        cout << "Months :";

        cout << endl;
        cout << "USER" << endl;
        cout << "------>" << endl;
        */
        //int user = 1;
        //for (int i = 0; i <= 529834; i++) //user count:529834
        //{
        stmt = con->createStatement();
        res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT user_id, add_time FROM m_business_record  WHERE(user_id = '1' AND type = '9');");

        while (res->next()) {
            cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
            /* Access column data by alias or column name */
            cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
            cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
            /* Access column data by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
            cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
        }
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException & e) {
        cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
        cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
    }
        /**
        for (int n = 1; n < 2; n++) {

            timestamp = 1548950400;

            if (timestamp >= 1546272000 && timestamp <= 1548950399) //Jan 2019 GMT +8
            {
                cout << "1/19\t";
            }
            else if (timestamp >= 1548950400 && timestamp <= 1551369599) //Feb 2019 GMT +8
            {
                cout << "2/19\t";
            }
            else if (timestamp >= 1551369600 && timestamp <= 1554047999) //Mar 2019 GMT +8
            {
                cout << "3/19\t";
            }
            else if (timestamp >= 1554048000 && timestamp <= 1556639999) //Apr 2019 GMT +8
            {
                cout << "4/19";
            }
            else if (timestamp >= 1556640000 && timestamp <= 1559318399) //May 2019 GMT +8
            {
                cout << "5/19\t";
            }
            else if (timestamp >= 1559318400 && timestamp <= 1561939199) //Jun 2019 GMT +8
            {
                cout << "6/19\t";
            }
            else if (timestamp >= 1561939200 && timestamp <= 1564617599) //Jul 2019 GMT +8
            {
                cout << "7/19\t";
            }
            else if (timestamp >= 1564617600 && timestamp <= 1567295999) //Aug 2019 GMT +8
            {
                cout << "8/19\t";
            }
            else if (timestamp >= 1567296000 && timestamp <= 1569887999) //Sep 2019 GMT +8
            {
                cout << "9/19\t";
            }
            else if (timestamp >= 1569888000 && timestamp <= 1572566399) //Oct 2019 GMT +8
            {
                cout << "10/19\t";
            }
            else if (timestamp >= 1572566400 && timestamp <= 1575158399) //Nov 2019 GMT +8
            {
                cout << "11/19\t";
            }
            else if (timestamp >= 1575158400 && timestamp <= 1577836799) //Dec 2019 GMT +8
            {
                cout << "12/19\t";
            }
            else if (timestamp >= 1577836800 && timestamp <= 1580515199) //Jan 2020 GMT +8
            {
                cout << "1/20\t";
            }
            else if (timestamp >= 1580515199 && timestamp <= 1583020799) //Feb 2020 GMT +8
            {
                cout << "2/20\t";
            }

        }
    }
    cout << endl;
*/

}
```

Hope someone can point out my mistake and correct me. Thank you.

```
UPDATE : I fixed my early on error with some help, now left with 4 errors and some weird onE cuz they're in the .obj file but I'm not sure how to open it
1. LNK2019  unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl sql::SQLString::~SQLString(void)" (__imp_??1SQLString@sql@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
2. LNK2019  unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl sql::SQLString::SQLString(char const * const)" (__imp_??0SQLString@sql@@QEAA@QEBD@Z) referenced in function main
3. LNK2019  unresolved external symbol __imp_get_driver_instance referenced in function main
4. LNK1120  3 unresolved externals
5. identifier "SELECT" is undefined
6. expected a ')'  ---- (Line 36, at the query part 'SELECT.....')
ERROR 1 - 6 HAS BEEN FIXED
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NEW ERROR :
using try() catch() got an error of
ERR : MySQL_ResultSet::getString: invalid value of 'columnIndex' (MySQL error code 0, SQL state:   )
but I didn't use MySQL_ResultSet::getString
```

Comment: I hope it's not real db credentials here

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I have updated the new code and errors

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4559224/9387017

Comment: hmm the problem still persist after i add mysql_driver.h in

Comment: You must pass your query as string and also you forgot to close the bracket

Comment: thankss it helps and every error in the visual has been fixed.
now theres an error when the cmd pops out, lemme just update the post